# what is the proper way to format sql query in wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, code-formatting

i am trying to insert this in my wqordpress blog, i trid using with with  `[sourcecode language="bash"] apt-get update  [/sourcecode]` it works

```
[sourcecode language="sql"]  
create external schema spectrum 
from data catalog 
database 'spectrumdb' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/mySpectrumRole'
create external database if not exists;
[/sourcecode]
```

But for some strange reason in preview, it shows some extra encodings

```
<span class="hljs-keyword">create</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">external</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">schema</span> spectrum 
<span class="hljs-keyword">from</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">data</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">catalog</span> 
<span class="hljs-keyword">database</span> <span class="hljs-string">'spectrumdb'</span> 
iam_role <span class="hljs-string">'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/mySpectrumRole'</span>
<span class="hljs-keyword">create</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">external</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">database</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">if</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">not</span> <span class="hljs-keyword">exists</span>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
[sql]  
create external schema spectrum 
from data catalog 
database 'spectrumdb' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/mySpectrumRole'
create external database if not exists;
[/sql]
```